# How to bring \includegraphics in front of \rule

Tags: graphics

I am writing a CV with currvita.

I use the following code to make lines beneath each item header:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{\cvlistheadingfont#1}
{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-0.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth} 
{0.4pt}}\cvlistheadingfont#1}
{}{}
```

and this one to add a picture

```
\noindent % 4cm is the picture's width, -6cm by trial and error
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(\dimexpr\textwidth-5.5cm,-8.2cm){\includegraphics[width=5.5cm] 
{Foto}}
\end{picture}
```

I would like the picture to be in front of the line. Can anybody help me with that?

[image]

Edit: David Carlisle says I should change the order of the code. I don't find where to but the code for the picture for it to work. So here is my entire document, cleaned up. Can someone tell me where to but the includegraphics?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,longtable,picture}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the
 document is to be sans serif\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the
document is to be sans serif

\usepackage{geometry}
          \geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=20mm,rmargin=20mm}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{\cvlistheadingfont#1}
{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-0.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}   
{0.4pt}}\cvlistheadingfont#1}
{}{}

\newcommand*{\ac}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\tolerance=600

\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{\Huge CV\\}

\noindent % 4cm is the picture's width, -6cm by trial and error
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(\dimexpr\textwidth-5.5cm,-8.2cm){\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]   
{Foto}}
\end{picture}

\begin{cvlist}{\textnormal{\scshape Allgemeine Angaben}}
\item [Vorname, Name]   
\item [Adresse]             
\item [Telefonnummer]   
\item [E"~Mail]         
\item [Geburtsdatum]        
\end{cvlist}

\begin{cvlist}{\textnormal{\textsc{}}}
\item
\end{cvlist}
\begin{cvlist}{\textnormal{\textsc{}}}
\item

\end{cvlist}
\begin{cvlist}{\textnormal{\textsc{}}}
\item
\end{cvlist}

\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Unterschrift}
\cvplace{}


\end{cv}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: latex just lays out the items as they appear so add the rule before the image not after it.

Comment: If anybody should have the exact same issue, I solved it by defining a shorter line and changing that below the code for the picture back to the full lines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved it by her/his own telling only in a comment